# UI5 access other Model path data in a Value attribute

Tags: odata, sapui5

I want to access `[PATH_TO_SOME_OTHER_MODEL]` value. So that when the view loads the TEAMS can be filtered via oData V4 call itself

```
<Select id="TeamSelect" change="onTeamSelect" autoAdjustWidth="true"
    items="{
        path : '/TEAMS',
        parameters : {
            $filter : 'Name startswith \'[PATH_TO_SOME_OTHER_MODEL]\''
        }
    }" >
    <core:Item key="{Team_Id}" text="{Name}"/>
</Select>
```

What is the correct syntax to get the value from another model?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it directly in the XML. You need to create and add a Filter once both models are loaded.

Here a snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>MVC with XmlView</title>

  <!-- Load UI5, select "blue crystal" theme and the "sap.m" control library -->
  <script id='sap-ui-bootstrap' src='https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js' data-sap-ui-theme='sap_belize_plus' data-sap-ui-libs='sap.m' data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax='complex'></script>


  <!-- DEFINE RE-USE COMPONENTS - NORMALLY DONE IN SEPARATE FILES -->

  <script id="view1" type="sapui5/xmlview">
    <mvc:View xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" controllerName="my.own.controller">
      <Select modelContextChange="onChange" id="mySelect" items="{ path: 'model1>/Names'}">
        <core:Item key="{model1>Id}" text="{model1>Name}" />
      </Select>
      <Button text="Disable Filter" press="removeFilter"></Button>
      <Button text="Enable Filter" press="addFilter"></Button>
    </mvc:View>
  </script>


  <script>
    // define a new (simple) Controller type
    sap.ui.controller("my.own.controller", {
      onAfterRendering: function() {
        this.addFilter();
      },

      addFilter: function() {
        var sFilterQuery = this.getView().getModel("model2").getProperty("/filterQuery");
        var oFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("Name", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.StartsWith, sFilterQuery);
        this.getView().byId("mySelect").getBinding("items").filter(oFilter);
      },

      removeFilter: function() {
        this.getView().byId("mySelect").getBinding("items").filter();
      }
    });



    /*** THIS IS THE "APPLICATION" CODE ***/
    // create some dummy JSON data
    var data1 = {
      Names: [{
          "Id": 1,
          "Name": "John",
        },
        {
          "Id": 1,
          "Name": "Mark",
        },
        {
          "Id": 1,
          "Name": "Liz",
        },
        {
          "Id": 1,
          "Name": "Jane",
        }
      ]
    };
    var oJSONModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    oJSONModel.setData(data1);

    //create a second model
    var data2 = {
      filterQuery: "J"
    };
    var oJSONModel2 = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    oJSONModel2.setData(data2);

    // instantiate the View
    var myView = sap.ui.xmlview({
      viewContent: jQuery('#view1').html()
    }); // accessing the HTML inside the script tag above
    myView.setModel(oJSONModel, "model1");
    myView.setModel(oJSONModel2, "model2");
    // put the View onto the screen
    myView.placeAt('content');
  </script>

</head>

<body id='content' class='sapUiBody'>
</body>

</html>
```